# Asp.net text box is only returning the first value

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

C sharp newbie question...I have a simple asp.net form that has a textbox that collects phonenumbers to send SMS messages. If I bypass the form and hardcode the numbers using the following format:

"2133211234",#1233211234"

the code works fine. However when i try to use this same format using my form, the sms will ONLY send to the first number. I have a feeling i'm missing out on some property on my form that will accept all of the values.

also any idea how how i can add some lines of code that will allow users to enter numbers like this:

3123211234,4123212344
and have it converted to the format above when the number is submitted?

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is really not very clear. There's several things we need to know to help you, but apparently you're not interested in helping us help you. Maybe by tomorrow you'll provide more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "2133211234",#1233211234"

Why are you tying yourself to this format? Is this format to achieve any particular purpose? If not, then simply ask comma (,) separated number from user and then split that string based on comma(,). That should do the job.